# tf.estimator.Estimator from tensorflow_hub.module.Module

Tags: python, tensorflow, embedding

I would like to create Tensorflow estimator object from universal encoder. I am planning to pass this estimator to Amazon SageMaker.

Here is link to the object that I would like to create:
[custom estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/custom_estimators)

Here is universal encoder:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
  # We will be feeding 1D tensors of text into the graph.
  text_input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None])
  embed = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2")
  print(type(embed))
  embedded_text = embed(text_input)
  init_op = tf.group([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])
g.finalize()
```

Can I simply set `train_op = embed` in `tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec` arguments?